# Using onClick to remove item from one array and place in another in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

I want to be able to click on a certain element and then remove it from the player1 array and place it into the playCard array. Currently this is attached to a button on the page.

```
choseCard = () => {
    this.setState(({
        playCard,
        player1
    }) => {
        return {
            playCard: [...playCard, ...player1.slice(0, 1)],
            player1: [...player1.slice(1, player1.length)]

        };
    });

}
```

Currently this takes the first item from the player1 array and places it in the playCard array. I want to be able to select a certain element(card) from the player array instead of just taking the first element. I'm having a hard time thinking of the way to do this in react as I am still a beginner.

Is there a way to maybe move the selected card to the first element then use the above code?

Comment: can you share the code where you use `choseCard` function

Comment: <button onClick={() => this.choseCard()} >Player 1</button>

Comment: try passing in the index of the player1 element you are clicking and replace that index in slice of playerCard where you have 0, make required changes in player1 also as you need to update player1...

Answer (score 0):

You can insert whatever logic you need right above the `return` statement, then return the results:

```js
choseCard = () => {
    this.setState(({playCard, player1}) => {
        // change `index` to whichever index you want to remove
        const index = 1;
        const toInsert = player1[index];

        const player1Copy = player1.slice();
        player1Copy.splice(index, 1);

        const playCardCopy = playCard.slice();
        playCardCopy.push(toInsert);
    
        return {
            playCard: playCardCopy,
            player1: player1Copy,
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you see him telling he wanted to mutate the data and then pull it off with the same code... and also set state requires a new object all the way, but in your code you are manipulating then existing state, which shouldn't be done.. correct me if am wrong

Comment: Great observation. You're right, mutating the state directly can lead to bad side effects. I've updated my answer to copy the arrays before mutating them.

Answer (score 0):

try passing the index of element you are clicking on to the function, this might possibly work...

```
         choseCard = (index) => {
                this.setState(({playCard, player1}) => 
                  {
                    return 
                    {
                        playCard: [...playCard, ...player1.slice(index, 1)],
                        player1: [...player1.slice(0, index),...player1.slice(index,player1.length)]

                    };
                  });
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could pass the card object in the `choseCard` function

```
choseCard(card) => {
  const {playCard, player1} = this.state;

  return this.setState({
    playCard: playCard.concat(card),
    player1: player1.filter(c => c.id !== card.id)
  });
}
```

this is also under the assumption that each card has a unique identifier.